# Fix damaged GPT on mdadm software RAID array

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I have a RAID array setup with two member disks `sda` and `sdb`.

I am using `mdadm` along with Intel RSTe (for OS compatibility purposes).

I have the following errors.

---

```
sgdisk -v /dev/md126
Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.

Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table may
be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup partition
table when you save your partitions.

Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside
at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e'
option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition
table's locations.

Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data!
(Disk size is 950198272 sectors, needs to be 950198536 sectors.)
The 'e' option on the experts' menu may fix this problem.

Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last usable
sector is 950198502, but backup header is at
950198535 and disk size is 950198272 sectors.
The 'e' option on the experts' menu will probably fix this problem

Partition(s) in the protective MBR are too big for the disk! Creating a
fresh protective or hybrid MBR is recommended.

Identified 5 problems!
```

When only looking at individual disk e.g. /dev/sd[a,b], only one problem shows up :

```
sgdisk -v /dev/sdb
Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside
at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e'
option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition
table's locations.

Identified 1 problems!
```

My question is how should I apply the recommended fix (rebuilding the backup GPT header)? e.g. should I do enter the "recovery and transformation options" and select "e - load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)" on `/dev/md126` or on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` individually?

I keep thinking that if I write to `/dev/sda`, the disk will then look as corrupted and synchronization would occurs. Maybe I'm wrong.

You advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, after further investigation, I believe the problem has something to do with the fact that I am using whole disk for my raid array.  I'd like to understand how the member disk should have been prepared for this scenario and if there is a way to "clean up" useless / confusing partition information from the members disks.